# Using PHPMailer to send emails to Variable addresses

Tags: php, variables, phpmailer

I have a form I've created, and on completion they are asked to select person they want it emailed to from a drop down list.

My issue is how do I add that variable to the $mailer.

right now it is written like this

```
$mailer -> AddAddress('email@email.com','First Last');
```

how do i get my variable in there

```
$mailer -> AddAddress($emailAddress) - Doesn't work.
```

I've also tried

`"'"$emailAddress"'"` - this gives me - Invalid address: 'email@email.com' which is frustrating since that's the format it is looking for.

Thanks, let me know

here is the full code that I am using to call the emails

```
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; //     optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: $mailer->AddAddress($emailAddress); should work if $emailAddress = "email@email.com"; did you tried to echo $emailAddess in your code near $mailer->AddAddress($emailAddress); ? Can you tell us what "doesn't work" ?

Comment: I did the echo and then the page crashes. I also tried doing some crazyness of using a variable in the html drop down with the singlequotes and then call on the variable in the $mailer, but that also did not work.

I get Invalid Address each time i use anything other than the specific ('email@email.com').

Comment: I've also tried ASCII code to call the single quotes which also generates the \ in the value. 

&#39;

i haven't tried &#145; &#146; yet, but I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1):

The code given below works perfectly for me.

`$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);` // Pass the value from html form directly with the phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an

```
var_dump($emailAddress);
```

right before the `->AddAddress()` call and see what comes out. If you're doing this within a function, it's possible you've not passed $emailAddress in as a parameter, of forgotten to make it `global`;

As well, don't surround the email address with double quotes. It's not necessary:

```
$emailAddress = 'email@email.com';  // correct
$emailAddress = "email@email.com"; // correct
$emailAddress = '"email@email.com"'; // incorrect
$emailAddress = "\"email@email.com\""; // incorrect.
```

Comment: var_dump($emailAddress) - "email@email.com"

And then is shows Address Invalid, I've found that it needs single quotes to actually accept the email as valid.

This is where my issue is, since if I use single quotes I can no longer use the variable.

Comment: What is the exact error message? There's only two places where "Invalid Address" could be output from phpmailer, a private method (`AddAnAddress()`), and a public method `SetFrom()`

Answer (score 0):

If $emailAddress came from a POST, use stripslashes around the value.

Make sure the select box has the correct value in the markup (check your view source).

As suggested, echo the variable to check it.

Comment: I am converting the POST into a Global session, and then putting it into an array.

From there I am calling the Session into a variable, and then echoing the variables.

When I get the echo, it comes back fine. 

and when I try escaping with the slashes, i get the slashes in the actual variable.

\'email@email.com\'

Comment: I have my own mailer class.  But, they all basically do the same thing: build a header, sanitize some variables, and call mail().  You can edit the $mail class to echo the recipients (the first argument of mail()).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, there was an issue in my values.

Actually there were a couple.

Lets just saying some spelling was incorrect.

Thanks for all the info though!

Answer (score 0):

Try `strval($emailAddress)`, worked for me.